# Django - Find position of a record in a filtered list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-2.x

I have a Django app in which I have a DetailView Page. I also have a ListView which is paginated and also has a created by filter (only author can see the records added by herself). I want to pull a position in ListView of the record being displayed in DetailView.

I tried following

```
position = BankAcType.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-created_date').count()
```

But it gives total number of records and not the position of the particular record in the ListView.

The reason I need position is that I have "view details" button in the List View which takes to the DetailView and also Update and Delete buttons inside the DetailView. Thus if a user goes to Detailed View and then edits something and then clicks a "back" button on DetailView, I would like her to come back to the same page in the list she was on, instead of going to the first page of ListView.

The HTTP referer does not work in case user has edited a record, because in that case the user is taken back to EditView.

I have tried to do the following in the DetailView.

```
class BankAcType_Detail(DetailView):
    model = BankAcType
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BankAcType_Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        position = BankAcType.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-created_date').count()
        page = str(int((position)/6)+1)
        context ['page'] = page
        return context
```

and then in the template, I have the following code for the back button.

```
<a href="/master/bankactype_list/?page={{page}}"><button style="background-color: #42c8f5; box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px -7px rgba(60,60,214,1.00); font-weight: bold; color: #054d05; float: left;">Back to List</button></a>
```

Comment: The position? Exactly what is the reason you need the position?

Comment: Can you show the details of your listview, template, and furthermore explain *why* you need the position, it looks a bit *odd* that the position matters. Usually one has to fetch the primary key (or another unique identifier) of the object.

Comment: Edited the question to provide more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by pulling the primary key and then finding the position of primary key in the list generated by the query for listing.

```
        context = super(BankAcType_Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        blist = BankAcType.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('-created_date')
        position = list(blist).index(pk)
```